# Segmentation fault in a very small c program for accepting and printing a string

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, printf

Why do I get Segmentation error during execution of printf() ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char* a ;
    printf("Enter name: ");
    scanf("%s",a);
    printf("%s\n",a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `a` does not point to any allocated buffer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways of doing it. One is storing the input as a `char *` the other is storing it into an array.

**How to do it as a char ***

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    char *a = malloc(sizeof(char) * 20); // You can change 20 to the number of letters you need

    printf("Enter name: ");
    scanf("%s", a);
    printf("%s\n", a);

    free(a); // Don't forget to free. If you malloc memory, you must free it
    return 0;
}
```

---

**How to do it as an array**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE      20 // You can change 20 to the number of letters you need

int main(void) {

    char a[ARRAY_SIZE];

    printf("Enter name: ");
    fgets(a, ARRAY_SIZE, stdin); // Scanning in the letters into the array
    printf("%s", a);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize the variable `a` using either a malloc or declaring it as an array:

```
char a[20];

char * a = (char *) malloc(20);
```

Comment: It is preferred not to cast the results of `malloc` in C.